# Is there a process to upload an openjdk hs_err_pid crash file to the developers?

Tags: java

I have a hs_err_* file generated by an OpenJDK app, in the process of a core dump.

Is there a process to bring this to the attention of OpenJDK developers?

Comment: No there isn't.  The large majority of Java dumps are due bugs in applications and / or 3rd party libraries.  However, if you are sure that what you are seeing is an OpenJDK bug, you can raise an issue in the OpenJDK bug tracker: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa .  Be sure to follow the advice they give on submitting issues.

Comment: FWIW, it would be virtually impossible for someone to find a bug based *solely* on a hs_err_* file and a core dump.  You would also need to see the application code, and some hints as to what was happening when the JVM crashed.  (Bugs that cause hard crashes tend to be particularly difficult, because the cause could be a memory corruption that happened "some time ago".)

Comment: My application is pure java, it does not do any JNI so I am not sure how my application could cause a bug in the JVM. But I will open a ticket in the openjdk bugs area. Thanks!

Comment: What about the 3rd-party libraries that your application uses?   Are they "pure" too?  Is the failure reproducible?   And will you be able to give them an MCVE or equivalent?  Without one, they are unlikely to investigate your (possible) OpenJDK bug.

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of all these limitations.